# End User Password Change (Frontend) not changing the password 1.9.01

Tags: password

first post so go easy on me, please.

I've done as much searching on this and checking as my limited skills allow. 
What I can say is /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout
customer.xml appears fine.

I had the problem previously where it was just a blank screen on the reset PW link. This time (and annoyingly I cannot pinpoint when the problem occured) the password reset form appears, but it doesn't show a message to say it's been completed. Sure enough the password doesn't change.

I tried adding the following code to 
the resetforgottenpassword.phtml

[image: the piece of code added]
"
but not sure i put it in the right place. It didn't have any effect.

any help very gratefully received

thanks